# cannot execute int data on method?

Tags: android, gridview, bitmap

I have used code from 
[the Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/process-bitmap.html#concurrency) and there's just one thing that doesn't seem to work. I cannot execute the int data on bitmapWorkerTask because it cannot resolve the symbol. My method:

```
public boolean cancelPotentialWork(int data, ImageView imageView) {
    final BitmapWorkerTask bitmapWorkerTask = getBitmapWorkerTask(imageView);
    if (bitmapWorkerTask != null) {
        final int bitmapData = bitmapWorkerTask.data;     //this is the line that gives me the error
        // If bitmapData is not yet set or it differs from the new data
        if (bitmapData == 0 || bitmapData != data) {
            // Cancel previous task
            bitmapWorkerTask.cancel(true);
        } else {
            // The same work is already in progress
            return false;
        }
    }
    // No task associated with the ImageView, or an existing task was cancelled
    return true;
}
```

In case necessary, I'll provide my other methods as well:

```
class AsyncDrawable extends BitmapDrawable {
objectAdapter oa;
Bitmap bm;

private final WeakReference<BitmapWorkerTask> bitmapWorkerTaskReference;
private int data;
private ImageView imageView;

public AsyncDrawable(Resources res, Bitmap bitmap,
                     BitmapWorkerTask bitmapWorkerTask) {
    super(res, bitmap);
    bitmapWorkerTaskReference =
            new WeakReference<BitmapWorkerTask>(bitmapWorkerTask);
}

public BitmapWorkerTask getBitmapWorkerTask() {
    return bitmapWorkerTaskReference.get();
}
public void loadBitmap(int resId){
    bm = getBitmap();
    ImageView imageView = oa.getPos();

    if (cancelPotentialWork(resId, imageView)) {
        final BitmapWorkerTask task = getBitmapWorkerTask(imageView);
        final AsyncDrawable asyncDrawable =
                new AsyncDrawable(Resources.getSystem(), bm, task);
        imageView.setImageDrawable(asyncDrawable);
        task.execute(resId);
    }
}
public boolean cancelPotentialWork(int data, ImageView imageView) {
    final BitmapWorkerTask bitmapWorkerTask = getBitmapWorkerTask(imageView);
    if (bitmapWorkerTask != null) {
        final int bitmapData = bitmapWorkerTask.data;
        // If bitmapData is not yet set or it differs from the new data
        if (bitmapData == 0 || bitmapData != data) {
            // Cancel previous task
            bitmapWorkerTask.cancel(true);
        } else {
            // The same work is already in progress
            return false;
        }
    }
    // No task associated with the ImageView, or an existing task was cancelled
    return true;
}
private static BitmapWorkerTask getBitmapWorkerTask(ImageView imageView) {
    if (imageView != null) {
        final Drawable drawable = imageView.getDrawable();
        if (drawable instanceof AsyncDrawable) {
            final AsyncDrawable asyncDrawable = (AsyncDrawable) drawable;
            return asyncDrawable.getBitmapWorkerTask();
        }
    }
    return null;
}

class BitmapWorkerTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Bitmap> {
ImageView imageView;
objectAdapter oa;

@Override
protected Bitmap doInBackground(Integer... params) {
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
    imageView = oa.getPos();

    if (isCancelled()) {
        bitmap = null;
    }

    if (imageView != null && bitmap != null) {
        final ImageView imageView = oa.getPos();
        final BitmapWorkerTask bitmapWorkerTask =
                getBitmapWorkerTask(imageView);
        if (this == bitmapWorkerTask && imageView != null) {
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    }
}

}

}
```

I have no idea why this problem is occurring, but I think it might be something simple.

Thanks in advance!

Vidal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the field data is private you should add a getter or change the field accessibility to public

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to reference a field called "data" in the class BitmapWorkerTask.  As far as I can tell, that class does not have a field with the name "data".  I see a "data" field in AsyncDrawable instead.